# Which program to use to capture Java output as video

Tags: java, swing, video-capture

I need to capture the output of a Java Swing program as video for the purpose of demonstration. I have tried Taksi video recorder and CamStudio, both of them are taking the video as a small rectangle starting from the left upper corner, and the rest of the screen being black.

I want the video to be fullscreen, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i'm using FF plug-in [capture fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/capture-fox/). A general purpose screen cast tool.

(Has nothing to do with Java at all.)